# Relationship of iterators and STL containers

Tags: c++, iterator

I understand the general idea behind iterators and I can use them at a basic level, but I don't get what happens under the hood and the relationship they have with STL containers.

From reading http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/:

- Iterators are objects defined with a class template
- "Iterators are classified into five categories depending on the functionality they implement"
- There are different types of iterators (input, output, forward, bidirectional, random access)

**My assumptions are** (I will be using `vector` throughout as an example)

- In STL containers, for example `vector`, the iterator is a nested class template and is created for each unique `vector` type.
- An iterator being considered to be one particular type of iterators is just a concept because it ultimately depends on what is implemented as member functions in the `vector` class.

  - My reasoning is that for example: `std::list<int>::iterator iterator;` which is a bidirectional iterator vs `std::vector<int>::iterator iterator;` which is a random access iterator are both declared with `::iterator` and there is no distinction made.
- Functions like `begin()` and `end()` are overloaded in the `vector` class

I hope I am making sense, please correct me.

Comment: `begin()` and `end()` are not overloaded (per se), as `std::vector` has no base class (per se).

Comment: Iterator type of `std::vector<T>` is implementation-defined. It does not need to be a nested class template, it might be simply an alias for a pointer to the value type (`T*`). `begin` and `end` are member functions; why overloaded?

Comment: The first bullet point is already misleading. Iterators can be thought of as concepts, that may or may not get implemented by classes or class templates. But it seems the reference you got the information from is talking about `std::iterator`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I should have been more specific. Iterators don't have to be std::iterator right? is that what you're saying

Comment: @csguy Right, that's it! For example, pointers are random access iterators.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica i'm confused, are you saying the STL containers aren't defined the same across the board? and I thought begin and end would be overloaded but I looked at the documentation and I was mistaken

Comment: @csguy C++ Standard basically defines just API for containers and some requirements for their behavior. As long as these are met, implementation details are left to particular implementations of Stadnard Library. Look at source code of, e.g., [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3), [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx), or [Microsoft's implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/STL). All of them implement containers in their own way (source code).

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong from the beginning. There is no requirement in the standard, whatsoever, that "the iterator is a nested class template". It could simply be a typedef for a completely independent template instance. The C++ standard only guarantees that referring to `std::vector<something>::iterator" gives you some class that meets the requirements for a vector's iterator.

Comment: @ArneJ `std::vector<T>::begin` names an overload set. You are thinking of *override*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go point by point.

> Iterators are objects defined with a class template

Not necessarily. Iterators are objects [that have certain operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator). Pointers are such objects, as are objects of various class types.

Each container defines a member type `container::iterator`, and another member type `container::const_iterator`.

These can be directly (a nested class), or it could be with a type alias referring to some other typename.

> Iterators are classified into five categories depending on the functionality they implement

As of C++14, yes. C++17 and C++20 each introduce another category.

> There are different types of iterators (input, output, forward, bidirectional, random access)

Those are the (C++14) categories, but there are an infinity of *types* within each category. `std::vector<int>::iterator` is a random access iterator, and so is `double *`, but they are distinct types. These categories overlap, the definitions are in terms of previous ones in the hierachy. [RandomAccess](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) is defined as an extension to [Bidirectional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which is defined as an extension to [Forward](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator), which is defined as an extension to [Input](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator).

> In STL containers, for example `vector`, the `iterator` is a nested class template and is created for each unique vector type.

Mostly. In many implementations it is, but in the particular case of `std::vector<T>`, no rule stops an implementation from using `T *` as the `iterator` type.

> An iterator being considered to be one particular type of iterators is just a concept because it ultimately depends on what is implemented as member functions in the vector class.

Yes. C++ has a notion *Concept*, which are just labels for things that behave in similar ways. Because of how templates work, there does not need to be any relationship between the types that satisfy a particular Concept. Contrast Java and C#, where `interface`s have to be explicitly mentioned in the definition of a type.

> Functions like begin() and end() are overloaded in the vector class

This is literally true, but probably not what you mean. Each container does have *two* member functions named `begin`. `container::iterator container::begin()` and `container::const_iterator container::begin() const`.

There is also the free function template [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin), which is specialised for each container and also (C style) arrays.